# How can I detect screen rotation with QML

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, programming, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I've been trying to create a Ubuntu QML application, but when I rotate my screen while it is running on my tablet, the header is semitransparent and the content below is exceeding the screen's height leaving the top part of what should be visible hidden.

Is there a way to shrink page's height on screen's rotation to fit display's height?
It there any screen-rotation-signal?

Thank you very much for you help.

*My code:*

```
MainView {
objectName: "mainView"
automaticOrientation: true
useDeprecatedToolbar: false

width: units.gu(120)
height: units.gu(75)

Page {
    title: i18n.tr("game")

    Column {
        spacing: units.gu(1)
        anchors {
            fill: parent
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: rwhole
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
```

Rectangle's height seems to be kept on landscape causing it to overflow the screen. But it is possible MainView's size was not updated.

Comment: Just an off comment, but if you are not already, come join us in IRC at #ubuntu-app-devel -- This is a great place to find answers such as these.

Comment: Some quick photos taken with a potato to give you a better idea of my problem: https://plus.google.com/117415521410663758843/posts/NxtEsJV44K7